# Windows Phone 8.1 target in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I can not target Windows Phone 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 Premium.
Only Windows Phone 8.0.

When I search on Google, I can only find WP8 SDK.

I did find a [WP8.1 SDK update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=43719) but that didn't change anything.

Please help, what do I need to do to start a Windows Phone 8.1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you go through this before you start working on it, adding to @Jerome's answer.

[Preparing for Windows Phone development](https://dev.windowsphone.com/it-it/OEM/docs/Getting_Started/Preparing_for_Windows_Phone_development)

Answer (score 2):

Check update, Windows phone 8.1 project is only in VS 2013 UPDATE 2.

[Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx)

It is also necessary to install Windows 8.1 on your machine and not just Windows 8.0

Comment: also noted that in VS2013's new project Wizard the WP project template has been moved to `Visual C#->Store Apps->Windows Phone Apps`.